# Rails 4 and Devise - routing issue with sign-up page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise, routes

I have a routing question related to Devise.

I have model - Member (rather than User) and I have some custom routes

```
devise_for :members, controllers: {registrations 'members/registrations',
                         omniauth_callbacks: 'members/omniauth_callbacks',
                         sessions: 'members/sessions' }
devise_scope :member do
  authenticated :member do
    root :to => 'home#index', as: :authenticated_root
  end

  unauthenticated :member do
    root :to => 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
  end
end
```

My issue relates to my sign-up page when it fails (due to a validation failing).

The displayed URL is

```
http://localhost:3000/members/sign_up
```

But if validation fails it redirects to

```
http://localhost:3000/members
```

(this page does show the registration/new form and this form works fine if the input validates)

In contrast, on my sign-in page

```
http://localhost:3000/members/sign_in
```

if failing validation redirects back to itself

```
http://localhost:3000/members/sign_in
```

Now you may wonder why I am asking this. I have an implementation of growly flash messages to indicate validation failure. They work on all the different devise views except the sign-up one. This routing difference is the only difference I can see between them. I am guessing that if the sign-up page redirected to itself on failure, like the sign-in page then the flash messages will work.

Its an odd question but some insights on this routing/URL behaviour in devise would be really helpful.

Registrations_controller.rb

```
  class Members::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  # GET /resource/sign_up
    def new
      build_resource({})
      self.resource.user = User.new
      respond_with self.resource
    end

  # POST /resource
   def create
    super
    resource.user.ip_address = request.remote_ip
       unless resource.email.nil? || resource.email.empty?
       resource.user.email = resource.email
       resource.user.save
    end
  end

  private
    def sign_up_params
    allow = [:provider, :uid, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, user_attributes: [:member_id, :email, :first_name, :last_name, :institution, :city, :country, :job_title, :about, :tag_list, :picture, :ip_address]]
    params.require(resource_name).permit(allow)
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you post your controller code?

Comment: Done. I have just posted the registrations controller -  controllers/members/registrations_controller.rb